# Picking a discrete set in a continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability

maybe this a stupid question, however I could not solve it properly. What´s the general method to solve problems relating the probability of a given event in a set of discrete events picked from a non-discrete set of events?

For instance, given $n$ points belonging to $[0, 1]$, what´s the probability of there exists 3 points $a < b < c$ (among the $n$ points choosed) such that the equation $ax^2 +bx + c = 0$ has real solutions?

Or, given 4 points in a square, what´s the probability of they form a convex polygon with area ranging from $A_1$ to $A_2$ and perimeter ranging from $p_1$ to $p_2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's too vast a question to answer. The only correct answer is: follow a course in probability theory. You need to learn about random variables and sampling.

Comment: @Raskolnikov I´m mainly concerned with the two problems cited above.

Comment: OK, but for the first one, I think you didn't formulate it properly. As it stands, the only answer for which $ax^2+bx+c=0$ holds is when $a=b=c=0$ and you've excluded that case. besides $a,b,c$ are not points but numbers. For the second problem, it depends on how you pick your points in the square.

Comment: @Raskolnikov These two question were in a test that I did. The difference was that $n = 65$ and the other constants above assumed values that I cannot remember now.

Comment: As Raskolnikov said, this question is way too broad. If you're interested in these two specific questions, please post them separately as individual questions. The second one by itself is already a lot of work. If you do repost it, I suggest that you provide some motivation why you're interested in this particular question.

Comment: I corrected the first question. I forgot to put that $x$ must be real.

Comment: OK, but you certainly didn't reproduce the first question correctly. What is $x$? For the second question, I suppose you need to sample points uniformly from the square and then we can start to answer it.

Comment: @joriki But apparently the method to solve the first question is the same to the method of the second question.

Comment: @user40276: Why do you think so?

Comment: If that is the case, why are you first withholding that information from us? Why doing only half the work? And expect that we do our part?

Comment: @joriki Because both questions were in the same exercise in the test that I did.

Comment: @Raskolnikov "that information from us"? I´m not withholding any information.

Comment: You didn't tell us that the problems were related so closely. I think we can keep the question open for now, with the correction of your first problem, it seems OK. At least, we can in principle help you solve both these problems.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Sorry for the insistence, but I didn´t understand exactly what´s the problem with the first question (I´ve edited it again) ?

Comment: I'm surprised to hear both that someone posing exercises thought that these two problems belong in the same exercise and that they thought the second problem was suitable as an exercise in a test. I'll be keen to see any simple solutions of the second problem; from my experience with geometric probability problems, I would have expected the second problem to be a complete nightmare.

Comment: @joriki The question in the test was if the probability was less or greater than other one given (I don´t remember now). I don´t know if it makes the question any easier.

Comment: @user40276: Please don't do that; what a frustrating waste of time. Next time you ask a question, please present all the information up front. Yes, that makes the question several orders of magnitude easier (of course depending on how close the value to compare against was to the true value).

Comment: The first probability when $n=3$ would be $\frac{11}{20}$. And?

Comment: @Did In case $n=3$, I find $P(b^2>4ac)=\frac16$ (even supported by numerical evidence). How do you get $\frac{11}{20}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen By trying to do the computations in my head and making a mistake. Your $\frac16$ is correct.

Comment: @joriki Sorry. I don't know exactly what's relevant in probability.

Comment: @user40276: Yes -- it's in the nature of things that one doesn't know exactly what's relevant when asking a question -- that's why it's a good idea, when reproducing a problem, to reproduce it exactly and not leave off bits that seem irrelevant to you, precisely because before understanding the problem you might not know exactly what parts of it are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, note that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has real solutions if $b^2\ge 4ac$.

The following will investigate the case $n=3$ exactly and give lower estimates for bigger $n$:

If $0<x_1<x_2<\ldots <x_n<1$ are our random numbers,
we investigate the case $(a,b,c)=(x_1,x_{n-1},x_n)$ further as that is the constellation where we expect $b$ to be as relatively close to $c$ as possible and at the same time $a$ as small as possible. In other words, if any triple with $c=x_n$ exists, then replacing $b$ with $x_{n-1}$ gives us another such triple and so does replacing $a$ with $x_1$.
For $0<r<1$, the probability that $x_n<r$ equals $r^n$ (the probability that $n$ numbers are $<r$). If we know $x_n$, then $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ are uniformly distributed in $[0,x_n]$. Therefore, 
$$\tag1P(x_{n-1}<rx_n)=r^{n-1}.$$
Similarly, $$\tag2P(x_1<sx_{n-1})=1-(1-s)^{n-2}.$$
Now with independent(!) random variables $R=\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}=\frac bc$ and $S=\frac{x_1}{x_{n-1}}=\frac ab$, we want to calculate $P(R\ge 4S)$. 
With the densitiy function for $R$ obtained from $(1)$, this turns out to be
$$\tag3\begin{align} &\int_0^1\left(1-\left(1-\frac r4\right)^{n-2}\right)\cdot (n-1)r^{n-2}\,\mathrm dr.\end{align}$$

If $n=3$, then $(3)$ gives the *exact* answer $\frac16$.

If $n=4$, then $(3)$ evaluates to $\frac{27}{80}$, but gives only a lower estimate for the probability asked for (we are missing the cases where $x_3^2<4x_1x_4$, but $x_2^2>4x_1x_3$). By numerical experimentation, the correct answer seems to be $\approx 0.352$ (compared to $\frac{27}{80}=0.3375 $).

If $n=5$, then $(3)$ evaluates to $\frac{271}{560}\approx0.48$ as lower bound (numerical estimation for correct value: $0.505$) and for $n>19$ the result of $(3)$ is $>0.99$.

A better approximation in case $n>3$ may be obtained by investigating *three* independent random variables $R_1=\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$, $R_2=\frac{x_{n-2}}{x_{n-1}}$, $S=\frac{x_1}{x_{n-2}}$ and find $P(R_2>4S\lor R_1>4R_2S)$ by integration.